# Problemas con JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy teniendo problemas al declarar la ruta actual en el que esta el usuario final

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es un problema de como incluis los archivos js, estas agregando jQuery antes que usuario.js?

Comment: Por favor, no pongas el código o los mensajes de error como imágenes, eso hace que no se puedan buscar y hacen tu pregunta difícil de encontrar (además de que hay usuarios que pueden tener problemas a la hora de ver las imágenes). Lee [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos si en esa línea te dice undefined es que en ningún momento esta declarada, ademas por lo que veo estas usando JQuery entonces su código debería quedar a manera de ejemplo del modo siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      console.log("Hola Mundo");
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Nota que al inicio declaro la librería que ocupo ua que como notas estas usando el signo de pesos $ que es indicativo de JQuery.

Siempre va primero la librería que uses y luego tu código escrito por ti mismo

Comment: muchas gracias... pero por que no se almacena en el local storage? ya que cuando inicio sesion me aparece de la siguiente manera la url http://localhost/appEmpresas/null